# ESP32 Arduino framework Preferences::getBytesLength() always returning nvs_get_blob len fail error

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I would use Preferences class to manage some simple setup data in my application and to assure data are not corrupted I added a CRC32 check function. To simplify the CRC32 calculation I want to use Preferences::getBytesLength(const char* key) and Preferences::getBytes(...) together but both do not work returning always this error:

**[Preferences.cpp:503] getBytesLength(): nvs_get_blob len fail: deviceSetup NOT_FOUND**

where deviceSetup is the name/label of my Preferences object.

This is my test code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Preferences.h>
#include <CRC.h>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PUBLIC SETUP DATA MANAGED USING Preferences
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
IPAddress _localIP;
IPAddress _localMask;
IPAddress _gatewayIP;
IPAddress _dns1;
IPAddress _dns2;
bool _dhcpOn;

int32_t _gmtOffsSecs = 0;
int32_t _daylightOffsSecs = 0;

Preferences _setupData;
Preferences _setupCRC;

uint32_t setupDataCalcCrc(Preferences& prefData, const char prefStr[])
{
   size_t setupDataSize = prefData.getBytes(prefStr, NULL, 0);
   Serial.print("setupDataCalcCrc setupDataSize = "); Serial.println(setupDataSize);
   setupDataSize = prefData.getBytesLength(prefStr);
   Serial.print("setupDataCalcCrc setupDataSize = "); Serial.println(setupDataSize);
   uint8_t buf[setupDataSize];
   size_t readDataSize = prefData.getBytes(prefStr, buf, setupDataSize);
   Serial.print("setupDataCalcCrc readDataSize = "); Serial.println(readDataSize);
   uint32_t c = calcCRC32(buf, setupDataSize);
   return c;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() 
{
   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Serial.printf("esp idf version:%s \n\r",esp_get_idf_version());

   _setupData.begin("deviceSetup", false);
   _localIP = IPAddress(192,168,1,99);
   Serial.print("localIP: "); Serial.println(_localIP);

   _setupData.putString("localIP", _localIP.toString());
   uint32_t crc = setupDataCalcCrc(_setupData, "deviceSetup");

   _localIP = IPAddress(0,0,0,0);
   Serial.print("localIP: "); Serial.println(_localIP);

   _localIP.fromString(_setupData.getString("localIP", "0.0.0.0"));
   Serial.print("localIP: "); Serial.println(_localIP);

   _setupData.end();
   Serial.print("setup crc = "); Serial.println(crc);
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this is its output:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x1b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13232
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
esp idf version:v4.4.6-dirty
localIP: 192.168.1.99
[    23][E][Preferences.cpp:503] getBytesLength(): nvs_get_blob len fail: deviceSetup NOT_FOUND
setupDataCalcCrc setupDataSize = 0
[    34][E][Preferences.cpp:503] getBytesLength(): nvs_get_blob len fail: deviceSetup NOT_FOUND
setupDataCalcCrc setupDataSize = 0
[    45][E][Preferences.cpp:503] getBytesLength(): nvs_get_blob len fail: deviceSetup NOT_FOUND
setupDataCalcCrc readDataSize = 0
localIP: 0.0.0.0
localIP: 192.168.1.99
setup crc = 0
```

I found it is an old problem that someone solved but not always, seems to me it is a bug somewhere in the source code so I searched also on the right github repository and also there seems it was resolved in a previous release but as you may see it is still a problem. At the moment in my application I disabled the CRC32 integrity check but I would like to solve the problem to re-enable the integrity check.
Any help will be very appreciated.
Massimo